# WordPress targetting specific post category on specific page

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello I am trying to target to target specific posts that are categorized to be displayed on specific pages.

I am building a home builders website, so I have post categories like

1) Homes for sale
2) Show homes
3) Features homes
4) Available lots

and I have pages that corespond to categories.
1)Show homes 2) Available Homes 3) Available Lots

What I am trying to accomplish is that I want to display combinations like this

On page (AVAILABLE HOMES)
        - All posts that are in category / slugs "Homes for sale"

On page (SHOW HOMES) - All posts that are in category / slugs "Show Homes"

I am not sure how to accomplish this....

This is how far I  got:

```
<?php if(have_posts()):?>
<?php while(have_posts()) : the_post();
      $categoris = get_the_category();

      print_r($categoris);

      if($categories){
          $class_names = array();

          foreach($categories as $category){
              $class_names[] = $category->slug;
          }

          $classes = join(' ', $class_names);
      }
?>

<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
        <div class="panel bodyHeight">
         <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
         <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
         <?php endif;?>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="large-8 columns">
        <div class="panel bodyHeight">
        <p>Price:       
                  <?php $custom_fields = get_post_custom(); 
                  $price = $custom_fields['price'];
                  foreach($price as $key => $value){
                  echo $value; 
                  }
                  ?>
        </p>
        <p>SqF:       
                  <?php $custom_fields = get_post_custom(); 
                  $sqf = $custom_fields['sqf'];
                  foreach($sqf as $key => $value){
                  echo $value; 
                  }
                  ?>
        </p>
        <p>Number of Bedrooms:       
                  <?php $custom_fields = get_post_custom(); 
                  $bed = $custom_fields['num_bedrooms'];
                  foreach($bed as $key => $value){
                  echo $value; 
                  }
                  ?>
        </p>
        <p>Number of Bathrooms:       
                  <?php $custom_fields = get_post_custom(); 
                  $bath = $custom_fields['num_bathrooms'];
                  foreach($bath as $key => $value){
                  echo $value; 
                  }
                  ?>
        </p>
        <p>Home Description:       
                  <?php $custom_fields = get_post_custom(); 
                  $desc = $custom_fields['description'];
                  foreach($desc as $key => $value){
                  echo $value; 
                  }
                  ?>
        </p>
        <p>Home Location:       
                  <?php $custom_fields = get_post_custom(); 
                  $address = $custom_fields['address'];
                  foreach($address as $key => $value){
                  echo $value; 
                  }
                  ?>
        </p>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile;?>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-4 columns">
        <div class="panel bodyHeight">
        <h3>No posts were found.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <?php endif;?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
<?php
    // The Query get all for posts categorized as 'featured'
    query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'featured', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
?>
<?php
    // The Loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
       // Get all custom fields
       $custom_fields = get_post_custom(); 
       // pull a field name 'description'
       $desc = $custom_fields['description'];
       // print value
       foreach($desc as $key => $value){
        echo $value; 
       }
    endwhile;
?>

<?php
    // Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();
?>
```

If someone can edit this code to make it shorter or better please let me know I don't know if it works with out foreach loop..  But as is code works!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with custom post types. This allows you to create custom archives and taxonomies.

This plugin is for non-coders:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/

But as always, the codex is your friend:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

By learning to use custom post types you don't have to resort to any kinky code to make your goal happen.

To get an array of posts from a specific slug you could do something like this, where 'category-name' is your slug

```
$idObj = get_category_by_slug('category-name'); 
$id = $idObj->term;
$posts = get_posts( array ('category' => $id, 'posts_per_page' => 5));
foreach ($posts as $post) {

setup_postdata($post);

/** use the post tags here **/

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I already read the second link but I am under major time line here and I can't learn to make custom type in time. At the moment I have everything that I need correctly working the only thing I need is learning how to (FILTER) the current posts by category. 

what I have done now is created individual pages for each so I have page-show-home.php and I have page 'Show Home' use that page as template.   All I need now is a filter by slug / category

Comment: Ah, so I'm a little unclear.  Each page will know the slug, you just need to get posts from the category for that slug.  Is that correct?

Comment: Understand also that your slugs will not be "word word" they will be "word-word".  "word word" would be the name

Comment: If you look at the code above, can you tell me how to filter that code so that it targets only lets say posts with slug 'show-home' now it returns ALL posts... I got the rest figured out I am just stuck on this part..Thanks

Comment: Hi.  Yup I added the code to my answer.  It is what you want.

Comment: Think of the foreach as "the loop".  When fetching lists of posts, get_posts is preferred since it doesn't affect global variables.

Comment: I am trying to use your code but I can't quite wrap my head around it, how would I for example now fetch custom_field - value of - home description ?